# Is there any alternative for 'substr()'?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, string-comparison, c-strings

```cpp
char patern[]="AGAAGAG";
int n = strlen(patern);
int pat[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= i )
    {
        if (patern.substr(0, j) == patern.substr(i-j+1, j))
        {
            pat[i] = j;
        }
        j++;
    }
    cout<<pat[i]<<endl;
}
```

I can only use `<iostream>`, `<cstring>`, `<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>`. The output is `0011232`.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: `char[]` doesn't have methods. Are you sure you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: @zead seam The alternative is the C function strncmp.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo if we change the first two line with string patern="AGAAGAG";

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you

Answer (score 1):

As character arrays do not have a method like `substr` then an alternative is using the C standard function `strncmp` declared in the header `<cstring>`. For example

```
if ( strncmp( patern, patern + i-j+1, j ) == 0 )
```

Comment: I don't know how to than you really appreciate it

Comment: @zeadseam thank people by upvoting and accepting their answer